# Call a ruby method from a html file

Tags: html, ruby

I try to build a html page in which the innertext can be modified by a rubyscript file. The rubyscript runs permanently and the html page has a autorefresh (every few minutes) so that its content is changing. On the html page is also a button with which a certain method is called in the rubyscript file.

Right now my ruby script loads the html page, makes some changes and save the file. After the refresh the content on the html page is changed.

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'rubygems'

def currentTime
   doc = Nokogiri::HTML(File.open("Path/to/index.html"))
   doc.xpath("//*[@id='time']").inner_html = "#{Time.now}"
   sleep 10
   File.open("Path/To/index.html", 'w+') {|f| f.write(doc) }
end

def main
   while true
        currentTime()
   end
end

main()
```

I don't think it is the right way to do this and how can I call directly currentTime() by clicking the button on the page?

Comment: Use a proper webserver / webframework setup. One of lightweight frameworks is Sinatra.

Comment: I expect Sergio is correct, but could you clarify whether you intend to make a web service or page eventually, and are learning in small steps? Or do you have a different purpose for this HTML? Generally the connection between a button on a web page and the server-side code (like Ruby) is not direct, and you need a few more components in place before it will start to make sense.

Comment: the goal is to create a website which displays the status of our web-api (somelike like this https://dev.twitter.com/status). We gonna use the amazon cloud as a webhoster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour of browsers working with local files and code has some differences to a more complete web service. One of those differences is that you have no simple way to trigger server-side code, because there is no server. Your next step should be to re-implement your HTML generating within a web server environment, instead of writing to a file.

I recommend Sinatra for your first web service, although Ruby on Rails would also be a popular choice, there's too much code to show here. This is your code transferred as-is to a Sinatra application:

**app.rb**

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'nokogiri'

get '/main' do
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(File.open("Path/to/index.html"))
  doc.xpath("//*[@id='time']")[0].inner_html = "#{Time.now}"
  doc.to_s
end
```

If you run this e.g. `ruby app.rb`, then Sinatra will automatically start a local development web server, and you can point your web browser at the address which will be something like `http://127.0.0.1:4567/main` (Sinatra tells you which port it is using when it starts the web server). Now you can just refresh the page in the browser to get the latest time.

This is just a start. There are lots of technologies to learn further and decide between. For instance, using Nokogiri to parse HTML and exchange values is quite inefficient, and you probably want a template engine instead, such as `erb`.